# Clean install of IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003 ignoring 'web.config'?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-6

Any help with this would be really appreciated!

As the title suggests, I'm running a brand new install of Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6 and I'm basically attempting to mirror a live web server onto a new internal development server, which runs the same setup.

It's an ASP.NET site that relies heavily on URL rewriting (using Intelligencia). ASP.NET is set to run on v2.0.50727 on both servers. I've tried intentionally introduce syntax errors into the web.config and it just appears to be ignoring them completely, so given IIS 6 doesn't read the web.config, the rest of the site doesn't work at all (I get a 404 error, as a 'Default.aspx' doesn't exist since the web.config handles the default page rewriting).

Having looked at the Application Mapping, '.config' files are set to use the default 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll' which exists.

Is there anything else I may be missing?

Comment: Did you register your web application as Application in IIS? Or else it is just handled as subdirectory of some parent (maybe root) directory)

Comment: Ah, damn. This was partly the issue. I'd downloaded the code from the site, missing the fact the code sat inside a '/httpdocs' directory ad not at the root. So I've updated IIS to use this as the root.

This sort of resolved the issue; the site ran, but Intelligencia failed to work properly. I found I had "Verify that file exists" ticked for the Extension Mapping (under Configuration on the Home Directory tab). Unticking this has resolved the issue and everything works as expected.

So it was partly stupidity and partly misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

Have you run `aspnet_regiis.exe`? It is in the windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 folder.

If this is a clean install of IIS 6 that happened *after* the framework was installed, you will need to register it with IIS.

Comment: I've run this with the parameter of '-i' and it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

As in my reply to Axarydax, I'd misconfigured the directory structure.

That partly resolved this but Intelligencia wasn't working either, so to fix this I had to uncheck "Verify that file exists" in Extension Mapping for the Wildcard application map (under Configuration on the Home Directory tab).